# Spring Web Service Message Dispatcher overrriding

Tags: spring-ws

I am currently working on creating a web service using Spring -WS. 
I want to make the request reach my own Message Dispatcher Class. So I made the necessary configuration changes to web.xml and also my sping-congfig.xml file. 
I am seeing an error when spring loads beans for my Message Dispatcher,
it tries to look for a properties file in my package which has the Dispatcher Class. for Example if my class is AccountMessageDispatcher, it looks for AccountMessageDispatcher.properties file in the package where I have created the class, I can get it running by keeping the properties file there, but I want to keep the properties file under my resources directory which has other property files needed by my application.

Can any one help me or point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take a look to the default `MessageDispatcher` infrastructure, we'll that it reads appropriate proerties file - `org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.properties`.

As you see this file is located at the same package as the original `MessageDispatcher` class.

According to your concern, you are right: that file should be located at the `resources` dir for sources. But if you use normal build system like Maven or Gradle, all your `resources` are packaged to the target jar alongside with classes.

To achieve your requirements you just need to create the same dir tree in the `resources` as your original `AccountMessageDispatcher`.

Actually any Java package is a dir in the end jar.